# Check status of pv tool on remote machine

Tags: bash, pv

I'm trying to run the script on the remote machine. Simple `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
dd if=/dev/zero | pv | dd of=/test.img
```

I want to know if it is possible to see the status of pv when I run this script from my pc on machineB
`ssh root@machineB 'script.sh'`?

I expect to see the status of `pv`.

Comment: If you copy the script to machineB, make it executable and start it there then you will see the data throughput on machineB, if you are allowed to write to /test.img. You do not see the throughput of the network connection to the server machineB.

Comment: I'm running script from my pc over ssh via machineB. Script is on machineB.

Comment: compare: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=16384 | pv | dd of=/dev/null bs=16384` and `pv </dev/zero >/dev/null`